# Special characters([1;32m, [0m) printed in jenkins logs

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a python script which is running fine as expected from CMD. But When I am running it from jenkins, ASCI codes([0m,  [1;32m) are getting printed itself under jenkins logs.

I there any way I can add under same python script that "If script is running in jenkins, then handle that ASCI code. else continue."

Comment: These are ANSI escape codes that are supposed to be interpreted by the terminal. There is nothing Jenkins can do about them. It's the script's responsibility to figure out that its stdout is not connected to a  TTY device.

Answer (score 3):

Install the [AnsiColor](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansicolor/) plugin and enable it in the job configuration page choosing your matching terminal type:

[image: traditional job]

Or in a pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo '\033[34mHello\033[0m \033[33mcolorful\033[0m \033[35mworld!\033[0m'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your console logs should now display color codes correctly.

[image: console log]